# How can I assign the value of a css calc() to a css-variable, and not have it delay the calculation until the css-variable is used

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

I have been unable to determine from any explanation I could find, about when the value of a css variable has been set., so I conducted a test

The `html`

```
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="item1">
        <div class="included"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="item2">
        <div class="included"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

the `css`

```
        :host {
          display: grid;
          place-content: center;
          
        }

        .flex {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          width:800px;
          height: 300px;
          background-color: blue;
          --div-width: calc(100% - 10px);
        }
        .item1, .item2 {
          background-color: green;
          height: 100px;
        }
        .item1 {
          width: 80%;
        }
        .item2 {
          width: 40%;
        }
        .included {
          width: var(--div-width);
          background-color:yellow;
          height:50px;
        }
```

Note I did the test inside a custom element, hence the `:host` descriptor, however that is not important.

What is important is that I set `--div-width` as `calc(100% - 10px)` inside a div that is 800px wide - so would expect it to have a value of 790px.

However , from this screenshot
[image]

It is obvious that the calculation is being delayed until the place where the variable is used.  as the yellow boxes are just 10px short of the surrounding element.

Is there a way of telling css to set the value of the property as the element where it is declared, rather than where it is used.

I did try and proxy the variable - like this ...

```
          --proxy-width: calc(100% - 10px);
          --div-width: var(--proxy-width);
```

but it made no difference.

PS This is a trivial example, how I actually want to use it is to control the width of an item (a textarea) inside a custom element, dependent on the context, so I can make the element responsive to changes of the width of some outer container.

Comment: *Is there a way of telling css to set the value of the property as the element where it is declared, rather than where it is used.* --> no, this is not how CSS variables are designed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a "perfect" work around!.

The solution to this is to use the 'resize' event to read the size of the element you wanted use 100% on  using `getBoundingClientRect();`  and using the width returned to set the "calc" as width px - whatever

So for the example in the question I would use this code

```
_resize() {
    if (this.resizeInProgress) return;
    this.resizeInProgress = true;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        const container = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.flex');
        const bound = container.getBoundingClientRect();
        container.style.setProperty('--div-width', `calc(${bound.width}px - 10px)`);
        this.resizeInProgress = false;
    });
  }
```

I bind that function to `this` in my custom element constructor

```
this.resizeInProgress = true;
this._resize = this._resize.bind(this);
```

and this in the `connectedCallback` do

```
window.addEventListener('resize', this._resize);
this.resizeInProgress = false;
```

and in my `disconnectedCallback` remove it again with

```
this.resizeInProgress = true;
window.removeEventListener('resize', this._resize);
```

I retain the `calc()` function because in my real life cases as the amount subtracted is in "em" units

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to make an element responsive to changes in size relative to a parent container. The way I've done this (but relative to the viewport) is by using [relative length units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#lengths) like `vmin` along with `calc()` and CSS variables. This way, we can create a "responsive unit" whether its relative to the initial containing block or some other positioned ancestor.

The example below shows a `<div>` with nested `<textarea>` that is powered by responsive units. Since this `width` and `height` calculation is being done relative to the viewport even though the `<textarea>` is a child of the div. You could possibly swap `vmin` for a relative length unit which isn't relative to the viewport but relative to some ancestor like the custom element.

```css
.wrapper {
 border: 1px solid;
 padding: 1rem;
}

textarea {
  --w: 150;
  --h: 80;
  width: 200px; /* fallback width */
  height: 200px; /* fallback height */
  width: calc(var(--w) * 1vmin);
  height: calc(var(--h) * 1vmin);
  max-width: 100%;
  /* extra styles for demo */
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea id="demo" name="demo"
            rows="5" cols="30">It was a dark and stormy night...
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I understand this.  In fact I am using vw units as a temporary solution.  But the container is inside a grid and mutates (using @media queries) from 5 columns down to two.  I have to redifine my css variable inside each media query, but even then you can see its slightly out of sync with the container.  Hence looking for a solution based on using the 100% width instead.  I find it strange that this "delayed" application of the css text string (ie the calc() function) is not explained anywhere in any css documentation about the variables.

Comment: @akc42 *I find it strange that this "delayed" application of the css text string (ie the calc() function) is not explained anywhere in any css documentation* --> you are then reading the wrong doc. The spec clearly state this : *Custom properties are left almost entirely unevaluated, except that they allow and evaluate the var() function in their value* https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is good to know. Thanks for sharing the w3 spec link!